# How do approximate $f \in C(X)$ by maximums of bump type functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Let $B \subset C(X)$ be such that if $K \subset X$ is compact and $U \subset X$ is open and $K \subset U$, then there exists $f \in B$ such that $\chi_K \leq f \leq \chi_U$.

How can I show that any $g \in C(X)$ can be approximated by a function of the form $\max(c_1f_1, \dots, c_nf_n)$ where $c_i \geq 0$, $f_i \in B$?

Comment: Can' you just take $g(x)=M\cdot f(x)$ where $M=\max g$ and $f(x)=\frac 1Mg(x)$? This works with $K=\{\,x\in X\mid g(x)=M\,\}$ and $U=X$ .... I'm assuming your $\subset$ stands for $\subseteq$, not $\subsetneq$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry I meant to define $B$ differently (fixed now). Yes $\subset$ stands for $\subseteq$.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. Let $g \in C(X)$. Assume $0 \leq g \leq 1$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. For each $0 \leq i \leq N$, there exists $f_i \in B$ such that $g^{-1}([\frac{i}{N}, \frac{i + 1}{N}]) \prec f_i \prec g^{-1}((\frac{i - 1}{N}, \frac{i + 2}{N}))$. Let $f = \max_{0 \leq i \leq N}\frac{i}{N}f_i$. Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Let $0 \leq k \leq N$ be such that $\frac{k}{N} \leq g(x) < \frac{k + 1}{N}$. Then $f_i(x) = 0$ for $i < k - 1$ and $i > k + 1$. Thus $\frac{k}{N} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{k + 1}{N}$. Thus $|f(x) - g(x)| \leq \frac{1}{N}$. Thus $\lVert f - g \rVert \leq \frac{1}{N}$.